# What is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[2x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[2x]$, how does a nonzero prime ideal look like?

An element of $R$ is of the form $$f(x) = a_0 + a_1(2x) + a_2(2x)^2 +... + a_n(2x)^n, a_i \in \mathbb{Z}.$$ Comparing with the case of $S = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, a nonzero prime ideal of $S$ is of the form $(p)$ for a prime $p$ or $(f(x))$ for irreducible $f$ or $(p,f(x))$ for $f$ irreducible modulo $p$, as seen in Mumford's drawing.

I believe that $(p)$ remain as prime ideals in $R$ for a prime $p$ but a polynomial like $2x^2+2x+2$ is questionably prime because we cannot write it as $2\cdot(x^2+x+1)$ since the latter term doesn't belong to $R$, and by this reasoning even $(2x)$ has to be prime. Or did I get some obvious things wrong? I'm so confused.

**EDIT.** In the comment by user26857 below, $2x^2+2x+1$ obviously cannot be inside $R$, since there is no way to obtain the term $2x^2$. By the isomorphism $S \rightarrow R$, given by $f(x) \mapsto f(2x)$, it seems like there isn't much work to be done to classify all prime ideals of $R$.

Comment: Well you have the obvious surjective ringhomomorphism $S \to \mathbb{Z}[2x]$. If you have a prime ideal in $ \mathbb{Z}[2x]$ it's preimage is a prime ideal in $S$, so it's of the form $(p),(f(x))$ or $(p,f(x))$. So your prime ideal must be an image of these. Can you fill out the rest? Your reasoning until now seems to be correct.

Comment: @BenS. Ok the definition of this map I hope to clarify, it definitely can't be the map sending $f(x)$ to $f(2x)$, since otherwise the element $2x^2+2x+2$ has no preimage in $S$.

Comment: My mistake, this map isn't surjective, I think I thought that $\mathbb{Z}[2x]$ was defined to be the image of this map, so you're right. Another approach would be too look at the inclusion map $i:\mathbb{Z}[2x] \to  S$, and look at preimages. That wouldn't neccesarily classify all prime ideals, but it would give you some examples, for examples $(p)$ for $p$ prime.

Comment: @BenS. No worries, my aim was to just use this question for some observations. My actual ring of interest is $\mathbb{Z}[2x,2x^2,2x^3,...]$. I had to find a prime ideal minimal over $(2)$. For a start, (2) isn't prime since $(2x)^2 = 4x^2 = 2(2x^2) \in (2)$ but $(2x) \neq (2)$. Same for $(2,2x)$, we have $(2x^2)^2 = 4x^4 = 2(2x^4) \in (2,2x)$ but $(2x^2) \neq (2,2x)$. By this reasoning, it seems like the minimal prime ideal has to be $(2,2x,2x^2,2x^3,...)$. But back to the question, we probably wouldn't run into such an ideal since $R$ is noetherian.

Comment: @BenS. Thanks for the map suggestion, I now recall the going up and down stuff, will have a good hard thought about it.

Comment: @KelvinLian Why do you think that $2x^2+2x+2$ belongs to $\mathbb Z[2x]$? In fact, $\mathbb Z[2x]=\{f(2x):f\in\mathbb Z[x]\}$ and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[x]$.